# Crash after share by email or sms in iOS swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to share some content. It my app crashes after I send email or sms. The emails and sms received. It works good with all other types. 
I added Social framework and imported Social to that class

My code:

```
    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.mstcode.com")
    {
        let messageStr = "Learn how to build iPhone apps"
        let shareItems = [messageStr, myWebsite]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        }
        self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Comment: Please add screens with steps that you are following.

Comment: That sort of stuff isn't access via the general tab its accessed via the accounts tab in preferences. What version of Xcode are you using?